# Acessar métodos type webservice com php

Tags: php, web-service, soap, wsdl

Tenho um wsdl que me retorna todas as informações necessárias para o consumo. É um sistema corporativo e eu preciso acessar a parte relacionada a busca de um itinerário de vôos, para preencher um motor de buscas de passagens aéreas.

As funções eu consigo acessar normalmente, inclusive já obtive retorno. Porém, ao tentar acessar um método (buscado com o __getTypes) sempre me retorna o erro "**Function x is not a valid method for this service**".

Parte do código que eu preciso acessar:

```
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:br.tur.advance.etkt.ws.bean">
  <import namespace="urn:br.tur.advance.etkt.ws.service"/>
  <import namespace="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap"/>
  <import namespace="http://bean.ws.etkt.advance.tur.br"/>
  <import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
  <complexType name="ItineraryBean">
    <sequence>
      <element name="airlineCode" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
      <element name="arrTime" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
      <element name="date" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
      <element name="depTime" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
      <element name="destination" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
      <element name="flightNumber" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
      <element name="origin" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
      <element name="seatClass" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
      <element name="tarifBase" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
    </sequence>
  </complexType> ...
```

Tentei com curl (o que me parece improvável) e com a classe Soap Client do PHP e sempre me retorna o mesmo erro. Vi em alguns fóruns que seria necessário o uso da **StdClass** mas não tenho ideia de como por em prática.

Tentei também acessar dessa forma, em que **ItineraryBean** é o método que eu preciso preencher para retornar as ofertas de passagens aéreas.

```
$tickets = $client -> ItineraryBean(array('arrTime'=>'25/06/2018', 'date'=>'', 'depTime'=>'30/06/2018', 'destination'=>'POA', 'origin'=>'GRU'));
```

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: `ItineraryBean` é um complexType e não um método. Como o nome bem informa, `__getTypes` retorna os tipos do WSDL e não os métodos/funções. Para as funções, utilize `__getFunctions()`

Comment: @GabrielHeming eu não consigo acessar esse complexType? Pois preciso dele, as functions eu consegui normalmente.

Comment: ComplexType não é um acesso, é a definição de um tipo, exatamente como uma classe. Apenas define um formato de dado, quais propriedades e o tipo de cada propriedade. O tipo pode ser uma entrada e/ou saída de um método, mas não é um método. Procure no WSDL e você poderá localizar qual método utiliza este tipo.

Comment: @GabrielHeming Eu busco pelo ItineraryBean, correto? Há outro complexType que chama ele... Se complexType é a definição de um tipo, então eu também não consigo fazer nada com ele?

Comment: Exato. Se ele está em outro tipo, você deve verificar aonde esse novo tipo está sendo utilizado. E assim por diante.